# Firestore orderBy boolean and timestamp

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a scenario where I need to paginate records in a collection based on a boolean and a timestamp field. So something like:

```
collection('jobs', ref =>
    ref.orderBy('asap', 'desc')
       .orderBy('posted')
       .startAfter(offset)
       .limit(this.batchSize)
```

`asap` is a boolean and `posted` is timestamp.

Basically I need to show a list of records where first records in the list are the `asap=true` ones and also these should then be ordered by posted date. And the list continues with records having `asap=false` and of course all these should be ordered by the posted date.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Hello, what did you try? Does this query works?

Comment: My workaround was to change the boolean field into a number(priority) and I passed 2 arguments to the startAfter cursor with both the fields from last paginated record. I assume it reduced the ambiguity and seems to work as expected, although there is a small chance that there would be multiple records with same timestamp and same priority. I'm not sure if data will be correctly returned in this case.